# How to write the truth table for a proposition and then determine its shortest possible equivalent expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$(r\leftrightarrow \neg p)\wedge p\wedge (q\rightarrow \neg (p\oplus q))$$

Steps I took:

I broke up the proposition into bits and pieces and assigned them to variables as such:

$a=(p\oplus q)$, $b=(q\rightarrow \neg a)$, $c=(r\leftrightarrow \neg p)$

I wrote up the following truth table:

[image]

After looking at the truth table, I came up with $(r\leftrightarrow \neg p)\wedge p$ as the shortest possible equivalent expression. However, I don't think this is the right answer. How do I go about figuring the shortest possible equivalent expression?

Comment: maybe use a karnaugh map?

Comment: I haven't studied that yet.

Comment: I guess you can simplify it to $¬r \wedge p$

Comment: I put it into wolfram alpha and got that same answer, but my question is why? How can I arrive at that solution by myself?

Comment: check your table, see in which rows you have truth for both b,c and p. You will find that it only depends on r and p.

Comment: I see that; however, this is only after it has been pointed out to me. How can I find this solution more easily?

Comment: I guess the easiest way is like you did, make a table and look at the rows where your formula holds. later you will study techniques which allow you to use easier ways to simplify logic formulas.

Comment: So, at this point, I have to literally go through all the rows and columns to see where it will be the same truth values as my original expression? That sounds very inefficient.

Comment: tell me which topics you already discussed in the lecture?

Comment: Introduction to formal proofs, scratched the surface of truth tables, logical operators, and De Morgan's laws.

Comment: oh, sorry. I took time again to look at your table and I see you made some mistakes. this changes the result of course. check your values again for $a$ etc..  From deMorgan laws you can also directly manipulate your formula to get it into a more simple form, but it takes some practice.

Comment: I will check in a moment, but it seems like my end result was correct. (I plugged the proposition into an online truth table generator.)

Comment: does $\oplus$ indicate OR or XOR?

Comment: It indicates XOR

Comment: oh, ok, then everything is good ;)

Comment: Does simplifying with de Morgan's laws still apply then?

Answer (score 1):

$$(r\leftrightarrow \neg p)\wedge p\wedge (q\rightarrow \neg (p\oplus q))$$

is the same as

$$\neg r\wedge p\wedge (q\rightarrow \neg (p\oplus q))$$

because $$\neg p \wedge p$$ can not be true. This furthermore simplifies to

$$\neg r\wedge p$$

because we know $p$ must be true and therefore $$\neg (p\oplus q)$$
is the same as
$$q.$$

Comment: How did you get from $(r\leftrightarrow \neg p)$ to $p\wedge \neg r$ ?